# google-http-client vs google-http-java-client tags FIGHT!

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

We have two tags that mean the same thing. One needs to go.

[google-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-http-client) and [google-http-java-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-http-java-client)

They both appear to be intended to refer to the same exact thing.

I think [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) + [google-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-http-client) should be sufficient.

Comment: Would synonymizing the two together be sufficient (and letting google-http-client win that fight)?

Comment: There's only 36 open questions tagged [tag:google-http-java-client]. I think it would be enough to retag them to [tag:java] + [tag:google-http-client], like you suggest.

Comment: I cleaned up some of them but do not have time to do all of them.

Comment: Looks like they're all gone.... poof!